# Haskell hdbc-odbc connection to Sybase database only works if trace function is used

Tags: haskell, odbc, sybase, hdbc

I am trying to connect to a Sybase database using hdbc-odbc via unixODBC and freetds. The following lines should be expected to open a connection, prepare a query on it, execute it and disconnect.

```
  conn <- connectODBC connectionString
  statement <- prepare conn $ queryString query
  execute statement []
  dataSet <- fetchAllRowsMap' statement
  disconnect conn
  return dataSet
```

The result is, however `SqlError {seState = "[]", seNativeError = -2, seErrorMsg = "SQLRowCount: []"}`

Yet the following code works:

```
  conn <- connectODBC connectionString
  statement <- prepare conn $ queryString query
  execute statement []
  dataSet <- trace "Test" seq conn fetchAllRowsMap' statement
  disconnect conn
  return dataSet
```

Importantly, **neither** adding `seq conn` alone **nor** adding `trace "Test"` alone will help. At the moment, the result will be the same as it was without any of them, but yesterday leaving out `trace "Test"` still would result in one of two subsequent queries being succesful, with the other one yielding the same error as above. But what remained stable was the first code fragment above not working and the second one working.

Using PHP or isql, I experience no problems of that kind, which seems to show that the problem is at least in part on the side of HDBC. Also, that a use of `trace` can systematically make a difference between getting results and not getting them should definitely be undesired behaviour.

Is anyone familiar with this kind of problem or does have a hunch what the cause might be? Searching the web and SO so far has been no help at all.